# Corollary of Hahn Banach Theorem (quite simple question?)

Tags: functional-analysis

The corollary of Hahn Banach theorem states :

---

If $E$ is a normed space and $x \in E$ is a nonzero element, then there exists $\alpha \in E^*$ with $|| \alpha || = 1$ and $\alpha (x) = ||x||$

Proof :

Let $M$ = {$\lambda  x : \lambda \in$**R**}, a one-dimensional subspace of $E$.

Define $\alpha : M \rightarrow$**R** by $\alpha (\lambda x) = \lambda ||x||$

**Then $\alpha$ is linear** and $||\alpha ||=1$

---

And I don't see why $\alpha$ is linear.

For $\alpha$ to be linear, I think $\alpha (x+y) = \alpha (x) + \alpha (y)$

But then we can't say that $||x+y||=||x||+||y||$ is true.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\Bbb R$, we have $\alpha(\lambda_1x+\lambda_2x)=(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)||x||=\alpha(\lambda_1x)+\alpha(\lambda_2x)$, which means $\alpha$ is linear on $M$. It's easy to check $||\alpha||=1$, and by Hahn-Banach extension theorem, there is a linear functional on $E$ as an extension of $\alpha$.

Comment: ohohohohoh thanks. I really got it now. Thanks.

Comment: Because every element in $M$ is $\lambda x$, we just choose arbitrary two element, and show the linearity.

Comment: @user924232 Sorry, the case $x=0$ is not true because of counter example $E=0$, for which the operator norm is 0, never 1. Correct?

Comment: @EclipseSun Hopefully u can reply too. Thanks.